# clarification on usage of come or go

Tags: sentence-choice

Which sentence is correct?

> I will go to your office tomorrow.
>   I will come to your office tomorrow.

Sometimes I hear people use "come" and sometimes "go."

Comment: "Come" talks about movement _toward the speaker or listener._ "Go" talks about movement _away from the speaker or listener._ Thus, both _"I will go to your office tomorrow"_ and _"I will come to your office tomorrow"_ describe the same action, but from a different viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Three people: you, Sam, and Cynthia.  The possibilities are

between you and Sam

> You tell Sam, "I am **coming** to you".
>   You tell Sam, "I am **going** to you".
>   Sam tells you, "**Come** to me".
>   <s>Sam tells you, "Go to me".</s>

You are talking to Cynthia about Sam

> You tell Cynthia, "I am **going** to Sam".
>   You tell Cynthia, <s>"I am **coming** to Sam".</s>
>   You tell Cynthia, "Sam told me to **come** to him".
>   You tell Cynthia, "Sam told me to **go** to him".
>   Cynthia tells you, "**Go** to Sam".
>   <s>Cynthia tells you, "**Come** to Sam".</s> *(Cynthia and Sam are in different locations)*